# C# Login Albumreminder.com

Tags: c#, html

i'm trying to use use webrequest to access and login to albumreminder.com, but i cant discover the appropriate form post formation. I've already use this process before, and every time use "&password=somthing&email=somth@somth.com" works for me, but isn't work in this one.

I have already use HttpWatch to try discover how data is send, but don't help.

here is the form:

```
<form name="login" action="/login/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" /> 
<p><label for="form_email">Your email address</label><input type="text" id="form_email" name="email" maxlength="320" /></p> 
<p><label for="form_password">Your password</label><input type="password" id="form_password" name="password" maxlength="32" /></p> 
<p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="form_keep_login" name="keep_login" value="keep" /> 
<label for="form_keep_login" class="checkbox_label">Keep me signed in. Uncheck if this is a shared computer.</label></p> 

<p><input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="submit" /></p>
```

and this is what i'm doing to get the cookie:

```
string formUrl = "http://www.albumreminder.com/login/";
        string formParams = string.Format("send=1&email=EMAIL&password=PASS");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: You say that using HttpWatch didn't help... in what way? What were the results?

Answer (score 1):

**Why it is not working**

In the form markup we can see

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

that means posting the normal way

```
string.Format("send=1&email=EMAIL&password=PASS");
```

will not work for you.

**Solution**

You need to do two things...

1. Set proper content-type header

your content-type should finally go as

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7db433550e64
```

here we are telling, form data is in multiple parts and each part is separated with boundary

```
---------------------------7db433550e64
```

No need to set content length, at the end we need to send "--" and server will understand that we are done sending the data.

1. Sending proper Post content

in post instead of parameters separated by "&", make sure your post data looks like below

```
-----------------------------7db2c2d550e64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send"

1
-----------------------------7db2c2d550e64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

test@test.com
-----------------------------7db2c2d550e64
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

testpass
-----------------------------7db2c2d550e64--
```

So may be you just want to parameterize this string by putting some placeholders like {0}, {1}... and then use string.format to replace them with actual values.

This should fix your issue.

Two more tips, do not change encoding to UTF-8 for your post data, unless you are sure it has some utf-8 characters. and you can make use of CookieContainer, instead of managing cookies your self.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I wish I could add comment to @Zannjaminderson's post, but my reputation is too low :), anyways WebRequest.Credentials implements ICredential interface and it only supports Digest, Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, and Basic Authentication schemes, and it will not support custom/form authentication, so it may not work here...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `WebRequest.Credentials` property rather than putting the credentials in the query string?